# Rails 4.0.2 Getting missing template error, but the template is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rail 4.0.2
Ruby 2.0
Mysql
webrick

My controller code is

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

def index
@contacts = Contact.find(:all)
end

def show
end

def new
end

def create
end

def update
end

end
```

In routes.rb file i put

```
resources :contact
```

I placed index.html.erb file in app/views/contact folder and code of index.html.rb file is as

```
<h1>My Contact List</h1>
<% if @contacts.blank? %>
<p>No contacts to display.</p>
<% else %>
<ul id=”contacts”>
<% @contacts.each do |c| %>
<li>
<%= link_to c.first_name+’ ‘+c.last_name,
{:action => ‘show’, :id => c.id} -%>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Even webrick server is working well but i am getting template missing error. But template is present. Any suggestion. I am new to ROR.
Thanks

Comment: Why is your extension `.html.rb` instead of `.html.erb`?

Comment: sorry, it's typo mistake. file extension is .html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Add 's' to Contacts names 
This is Rails namespace convention for CRUD resources http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

```
# app/controllers/contacts_contoller.rb
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

#routes.rb
resources :contacts

# app/views/contacts/index.html.erb
. . .
```

Comment: I changed to resources :contacts but now i am getting No route matches [GET] "/contact/index" error.

Comment: Did You Changed the ContactController to ContactsController?

Comment: yes because we have `index` method, thus we have many contacts